# When i am submitting my form data into zoho leads then in console i am getting content security policy error

Tags: javascript, zoho

As zoho has announced its API v2.0. So I am using javascript to migrate from v1.0 to v2.0, but when I am trying to insert my form data into zoho leads.

I am using JSON to post data in zoho crm But when I am submiting the form, then it is showing IAM Security error. I am stuck on it. If anyone has any idea about it then help me to fix it.

Below is the javascript code I am using to post data into crm

```js
//taking input data from my custom form and storing in js variable 

var name = document.forms['myForm']['full_Name'].value;
var email = document.forms['myForm']['Email'].value;
var Referrals = document.forms['myForm']['referrals'].value;
var url = document.forms['myForm']['url_parameter'].value;
var website = document.forms['myForm']['Website'].value;

//converting above value into json object(key:value or api- name: value)

var arr = [{
  "First_Name": "name",
  "Email": "email",
  "No_of_Referrals": "Referrals",
  "URL_Parameter": "url",
  "Website": "website"
}]

//using ajax to post above data into zoho 

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(arr),
  async: true,
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function(x) {
    if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
      x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
    }
  },

  success: function(Response) {
    alert(Response);
  }
});
```

I expect that when I post form data then a new  lead is created

I have tried content security policy rule in .htaccess also used in header with  meta tag

I included this line in header

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script src 'self' *.https://scripts.zohospotlight.com/track' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

image of error:

[image]

Comment: I believe due to security reason you can't send data to different domain from browser if CORS is disabled from the server side. The best approach is requesting to Zoho from your server side. I hope it might help you.

Comment: **x.overrideMimeType()** should be **application/json**, not **application/j-son**. (RFC 4627)